# How to perform - operation on this relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am studying Proof, Logic, and Conjecture by Robert Wolf. A great textbook but the solutions seem to be nowhere.

In the chapter on relations, this question appears:

Let A={1,2,3}, B={2,5}

How many elements are in

(A $ \times $ B) - (A $ \cup $ B)

?

(I’m not even sure how to perform this operation since it seems like a set of ordered pairs minus a set of single digits doesn’t appear to be legal, in my opinion. I guess I don’t understand how these concepts are actually related yet. Any guidance? How can this operation be done?)

Comment: Start writing $A \times B = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in A \text { and } y \in B \}$ i.e. $\{ (1,2), (1,5), (2,2), (2,5), (3,2), (3,5) \}$

Comment: Then write $A \cup B$

Comment: And your concern is correct: no common elements: thus "subtracting" the second from the first will output the first.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you Mauro! That clears up a lot. Nice to know my mind was in the right direction. Thanks :)